# Error:The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio debug c# script on OSX, show a Error:
The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1.

This is a copy of the launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/hwapp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "externalConsole": false
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/hwapp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a copy of the tasks.json file:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i resolve this???PLS

Comment: I'm also getting a failure when trying to debug using [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/). =(

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacPorts, then this may be your issue, *(it was for me)*.

I've got this in my `.zshrc`, or `.profile` etc., to link to the MacPorts version of OpenSSL :

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib:~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
```

.NET Core works from here.

Neither VSCode OR [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) will debug though *(I get the error you're getting)*.

Mine is an issue with [OmniSharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode), here's the [link](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/src/coreclr-debug/proxy.ts#L97) to the file where the error is raised. You can verify the installation fails by entering `Debug: Download .NET Core Debugger` within the command pallet of VSCode:

To resolve this I created 2 symlinks for OpenSSL *(Not super elegant, but...)*:
*(You'll probably no longer need the above export with these symlinks)*

```
% sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
% sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Then I re-installed the C# plugin for VSCode, and re-executed `Debug: Download .NET Core Debugger` in the command pallet. I can now debug in BOTH VSCode and Rider.

---

**If this doesn't work for you, you may get some useful output/info from the above VSCode command.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the paths in `tasks.json` and `launch.json` with absolute paths.

For example in `launch.json`:

```
"program": "C:/Projects/MyProject/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/hwapp.dll",
"cwd": "C:/Projects/MyProject/"
```

in `tasks.json`:

```
"tasks": [
  {
    "label": "build",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "type": "process",
    "args": [        
      "build",
      "C:/Projects/MyProject/XXXXXX.csproj"
```

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem and I had to download the version that specified in the console error. And then 
follow the steps in this link.. make sure to open a new command prompt to execute the commands

https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows